# Getting error in type conversion php?

Tags: javascript, php

I stored a Javascript value to a PHP variable. When I use `var_dump` to print it, `var_dump` returns `int(0)`. It should display `int(10)`. I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a = "Hello world: 12345";
        var b = a.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
    </script>
    <?php
        $identity = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(b)</script>';
        var_dump($identity);
        echo "<br/>";
        $identity  = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $identity ); //removes everything except digits
        $ord = (int)$identity;
        var_dump($ord);
    ?>
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are using `(int)` to convert a long string into a number. You are understanding things wrong : you CAN NOT assing a javascript value to a php variable, what you can do is assign a php value to a javascript variable.

Comment: Just assigning some javascript to a string doesn't execute it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: then what should i do to get solve this out ?

Comment: Dear @UpendraSharma, to solve this out you have to understand how client and server languages work : when PHP code executes, JavaScript doesn't exist yet, so, you cannot assign a JavaScript value to a PHP variable (because the JavaScript code doesn't exist yet so it cannot execute). Once the JavaScript code appears in your computer (the client), the PHP code is gone, it no longer exists (it was on the server), so, once again, you cannot assign a JavaScript value to PHP (because PHP variable is gone). Get the idea? PHP can generate JavaScript code, but JavaScript cannot generate PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

> Where have i gone wrong ?

1. `JavaScript` code doesn't evaluate inside a `php` script, pretty basic.
2. You're trying to convert a `string` to `int` but `php` won't allow you to do that when the `string` contains **letters**, or **anything different** from **digits**.

If you use:

```
$identity = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(10)</script>';
$identity  = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $identity ); //removes everything except digits
$ord = (int)$identity;
var_dump($ord);
```

`php` will convert the `string` to `int` without errors.

Comment: i just edited something in my question, it is like that really, please have a look and let me know about the solution.

Comment: You cannot pass variable from JavaScript to php like that, it simply doesn't work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have this <h3 id="some"><?php bp_the_thread_subject(); ?></h3> in buddypress messageing plugin single.php file. I want to explode this with ': ' but i don't know how to do that. That's why i pick value of h3 using javascript and put that into php variable. so that i can get some results from database table using integer value.

Comment: `$myArray = explode("SOME DIVIDER", bp_the_thread_subject());`